# query click event for buttons inside a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I am populating a data-table from a model using a foreach loop:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
    {        
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none">@item.Id</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>@item.Description</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
                <button type="button" data-id=@item.Id id="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Each row of the table has an update and delete button.

I'm struggling to bind the buttons to a click event using jQuery.

Here is my script so far which is within the document ready function:

```
    var table = $('#productTable').DataTable();

    $('#productTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert(Product ID = ' + data[0] + ');

//Call delete function and pass in Id
    });
```

This is understandably showing an alert anytime the user clicks the row. How to I get it to only fire when the delete button is clicked?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried: `$('.btn-danger').on('click', function(){ //your delete function });`?

Comment: it's probably not a good idea to target `.btn-danger` because there could be other buttons with that class that you don't want to call the delete function on.

Comment: @JaeGeeTee, it will be calling just the clicked one, not every button with the same class.

Comment: @doutriforce but you'd be binding a click even to every instance of an html element with .btn-danger regardless of whether or not they are meant to delete anything.

Comment: @JaeGeeTee, ok, i get your point, but he's only using that class on _delete_ buttons...

Comment: At least on the posted html.

Comment: @doutriforce while your code works, its not the right implementation.

Comment: I would recommend adding another class to your delete button... something along the lines of `delete-btn` that can be selected easily in jquery.  per the conversation with @doutriforce.

Comment: @JaeGeeTee, yes, i should have added that he must use an _unique_ class for triggering the delete event. But that doensn't make it a wrong implementation. Thanks for your oppinion, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take *doutriforce* suggestion and bind the events to a class, for example:

```
$("#productTable tbody").on("click", ".btn-update", function() {
    // Your update code here
    // Use $(this) to access the button that triggered this event
}
$("#productTable tbody").on("click", ".btn-delete", function() {
    // Your delete code here
    // Use $(this) to access the button that triggered this event
}
```

I've used: **$("#productTable tbody").on("click", ", function);** because it also works for dynamically added elements (in this case, table rows).

Comment: Thank you. I added the btn-delete class to the <td>, updated the jQuery and is now working. I've used the following code to access the values within the row (for anyone else who is having the same problem).

var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()[0];

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler), it looks like you need to edit the selector that you bind the click event too, like this:

```
$('#productTable button#Delete').on('click', function () { 
    var data = table.row(this).data();
    alert(Product ID = ' + data[0] + ');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
const medias = document.querySelectorAll('._23fpc');
for (let i=1; i<medias.length; i++) {
    const media = medias[i];
  const firstClickable = media.querySelectorAll('._1JX9L')[1];
  if(firstClickable) {
    window.setTimeout(() => firstClickable.click(), 50);
  }
}
```

I edited the code copied from the internet, it kind of works
PS:I know nothing about coding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).